# General proposition that, if true, would immediately prove that $\sum\sin n$ and $\sum\cos n$ are bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, ergodic-theory, equidistribution

I know that the sequence $A_n = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \sin k$ is bounded. I suspect the following general proposition is true, and it could then immediately imply $A_n$ is bounded, as an alternative to the methods used to prove $A_n$ being bounded, as for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59589/show-that-a-n-sum-limits-k-1n-sin-k-is-bounded) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1206631/proving-the-series-of-partial-sums-of-sin-in-is-bounded).

> Proposition: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \to\mathbb{R}\ $ be a continuous (and therefore
> bounded on $[0,1]$) function with period $1$ and $\displaystyle
>  \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = 0.\ $ Let $\alpha$ be a positive irrational
> number. Then $A_n:=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(\alpha k)\ $ is
> bounded.

Maybe this can be proved using [Weyl's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl%27s_criterion), although I think we need a property of the sequence $\ \left(\alpha n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\ $ stronger than [equidistribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#), like [low-discrepancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence), to prove the theorem, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think you will be going around in circle here, because the Birkhoff means $\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n f(j\alpha+x)$ converges with rate $O(1/n)$ (a.e.-$x$) is precisely the condition there exists $g\in L^\infty$ such that $f(x)=g(x+\alpha)-g(x)$.

Comment: What's "the Birkhoff"?

Comment: It is not "the Birkhoff" but "the Birkhoff mean", i.e., an operator that take an ergodic transformation $T$ and some $L^1$ function $f$, and returns the $L^1$ function that is averaging the $f$ over the first $n$ iterates $f, f\circ T,\dots, f\circ T^{n-1}$.

Comment: @user10354138 But it is intriguing how completely differently the first comment (almost) parses if one assumes that "the Birkhoff" is a thing :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Funnily enough on my browser window the line wraps after the word Birkhoff :)  Maybe I should have added a link to Birkhoff's ergodicity theorem.